# Testing react component's number of children

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, enzyme

I am writing a test in React for the first time, and I am wondering is there a way to test the number of children components of a children component inside the parent component, so to make it clear, this is how to component looks like, I have cut it down to the parts that are relevant to this question:

```
<Modal>
     <RadioGroupField direction="vertical" name={`${fieldId}.resultat`} bredde="M">
          <RadioOption label={{ id: 'UttakInfoPanel.SykdomSkadenDokumentertAngiAvklartPeriode' }} value />
          <RadioOption label={{ id: 'UttakInfoPanel.SykdomSkadenIkkeDokumentert' }} value={false} />
     </RadioGroupField>
</Modal>
```

So, when I am writing a test for the Modal component I would like to check if there is a correct number of children components of the RadioGroupField component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { expect } from 'chai';
import { shallowWithIntl } from 'testHelpers/intl-enzyme-test-helper';

import { Modal} from './Modal';

const periode = {
  fom: '2018-01-01',
  tom: '2018-03-01',
};
it('should show modal component', () => {
    const wrapper = shallowWithIntl(<Modal
      fieldId="periode[0]"
      resultat={undefined}
      periode={periode}
    />);

    const radioGroupField = wrapper.find('RadioGroupField');
    expect(radioGroupField).to.have.length(1);

  });
```

How can I write that test?

**Update**

I have tried with using name and not string for the component and dive method, but all of a sudden I get an error:

> ReferenceError: RadioGroupField is not defined

This is my test:

```
it('skal vise sykdom og skade periode', () => {
    const wrapper = shallowWithIntl(<Modal
      fieldId="periode[0]"
      resultat={undefined}
      periode={periode}
    />);

    const textAreaField = wrapper.find('TextAreaField');
    const undertekst = wrapper.find('Undertekst');
    const radioGroupField = wrapper.find('RadioGroupField');
    const fieldArray = wrapper.find('FieldArray');
    const hovedknapp = wrapper.find('Hovedknapp');
    const knapp = wrapper.find('Knapp');
    const radioGroupFieldComponent = wrapper.find(RadioGroupField).dive();
    expect(radioGroupFieldComponent.children()).to.have.length(2);
    expect(textAreaField).to.have.length(1);
    expect(undertekst).to.have.length(1);
    expect(radioGroupField).to.have.length(1);
    expect(fieldArray).to.have.length(1);
    expect(hovedknapp).to.have.length(1);
    expect(knapp).to.have.length(1);
  });
```

Comment: check the example for the `children()` api http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/children.html#childrenselector--shallowwrapper

Comment: you need to find component instead of string wrapper.find(RadioGroupField)
and in expect you need to user expect(radioGroupField.children()).to.have.length(2);

Comment: based on Edit: you'll have to import all of those components and remove the strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to refer to components, use their name not a String as documented:

```
wrapper.find(Foo) // Foo component, not 'Foo'
```

> I would like to check if there is a correct number of children components of the RadioGroupField component:

Use `children()` as documented in the `enzyme` API

```
const radioGroupField = wrapper.find(RadioGroupField).dive()
expect(radioGroupField.children()).to.have.length(2)
```

References:

- [enzyme `find()` api](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/find.html)
- [enzyme `children()` api](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/children.html)

**EDIT:**
add `dive()` as this may be needed to render components (non-DOM nodes)

> Update
>
> I have tried with using name and not string for the component and dive
>   method, but all of a sudden I get an error:
>
> `ReferenceError: RadioGroupField is not defined`

Any components used in your tests need to be imported.

Here's an example:

Foo.js:

```
import React from 'react'

export const Bar = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {props.children}
    </div>
  )
}

export const Baz = () => (
  <div>Foo</div>
)

export const Foo = () => (
  <Bar>
    <Baz />
    <Baz />
  </Bar>
)

export default Foo
```

Foo.test.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { shallow } from 'enzyme'
import Foo, { Bar, Baz } from './Foo'

it('Foos', () => {
  let wrapper = shallow(<Foo />)
  expect(wrapper.find(Bar)).toHaveLength(1) // jest syntax
})
```

Comment: For some reasone the test is failing if I write it like that: ```AssertionError: expected { length: 0 } to have a length of 2 but got 0```

Comment: Edited answer to add dive() and locally verified. I'd also recommend checking if you're using the most recent `enzyme` version if it persists.

Comment: I have tried with dive now, and all of a sudden I keep getting an error, I have updated my question with new code.

Comment: Updated answer. You have to import your components.

Answer (score 0):

This also works:

```
const radioOption = wrapper.find(RadioGroupField).dive().find(RadioOption);
```

Comment: I have tried with dive now, but I get reference error, I have updated my question with the new code.

Comment: Both RadioGroupField and RadioOption are react components like Model component. Either it is created by you or imported from some of the node module. So you need to import both these components like you imported the Model component